# How can I do a counter session variable in the Dialogflow CX interface?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Something like **$session.var += 1** per time the dialog steps in a certain page (state).

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not possible, for certain editing I would use Webhook Integrations but the Dialogflow CX interface just supports logical expressions.